# jq: one jq command to update multiple values in Json file

Tags: json, pipe, jq, pipeline

i have below json file, i need to update all the key values using one jq command.

```
{
"changeDetails": {
    "chgNumber": "$ASKNOW_CRQ"
},
"environmentType": "$ENV_TYPE",
"fqdn": "$FQDN.visa.com",
"products": [{
    "action": "deploy",
    "attributes": {
        "artifactDetails": {
            "url": "$ARTIFACT_URL"
        },
        "containers": "$CONTAINER_NAME"
    },
    "productName": "$PACKAGE_ID",
    "cookbookName": "visa_springboot"
}],
"tpg": "O&I"}
```

Below jq command works and able to update only below keys in json file

```
. + {environmentType:"xz", fqdn:"abc", tpg:"mnop" }
```

using below sample, i am able to update all the keys by running multiple jq commands

```
contents="$(jq '.products.action = "abcde"' test.json)"
echo "${contents}" > test.json
```

Using below command it is creating multiple json file for each value update.

```
.products[].attributes.artifactDetails.url = "abc", .products[].cookbookName = "cookbook"
```

I need only one JQ command to update all the values in Json file and output should be redirect  to final.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, use '|' instead of ','.

E.g.

```
.products[].attributes.artifactDetails.url = "abc"
| .products[].cookbookName = "cookbook"
```